# Querying in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I have a Package table in BigQuery as follows:

```
 Packageid  Scanid  dispatchid  timestamp   status
   p1         s1       null        t1        'in'
   p2         s1       xxx         t2        'in'
   p1         s2       yyy         t3        'pkin'
   p1         s3       sss         t4        'iwi'
   p1         s4       eee         t5        'lhp'
   p2         s2       uuuu        t6        'uio'
   p2         s3       null        t7        'jsk'
```

I want to retrieve the following details:

```
Packageid   Latest-Scanid   First-Dispatch-time  Last-Dispatch-time   latest-status

 p1            s4                 t3                 t5                 'lhp'
 p2            s3                 t2                 t6                 'jsk'
```

First-Dispatch-time is the time when first time dispatch id appeared in the package scan.
Last-Dispatch-time is the time when last time dispatch id appeared in the package scan.

Is there any way to get the above table using BigQuery or uer defined functions in BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses windows functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select packageid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then dispatchid end) as dispatchid,
       min(case when dispatchid is not null then timestamp end) as first_dispatchid,
       max(case when dispatchid is not null then timestamp end) as last_dispatchid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as status
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by packageid order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by packageid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will note that this is for SQL Server and may or may not work in MYSQL.

```
SELECT Packageid, 
    MAX(Scanid) [Latest_Scanid], 
    MIN(timestamp) [First-Dispatch-time], 
    MAX(timestamp) [Last-Dispatch-time],
    (SELECT status FROM Package p WHERE p.timestamp = Package.timestamp AND p.Packageid = Package.Packageid) [latest-status]
FROM Package
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query is using one "dirty" trick (see not_null_ts) that allows to eliminate outer group by and rather have everything calculated in inner select

```
SELECT packageid, latest_scanid, first_dispatch_time, last_dispatch_time, latest_status
FROM (
  SELECT packageid, 
    IF(dispatchid IS NULL, NULL, ts) AS not_null_ts,
    FIRST_VALUE(scanid) OVER(PARTITION BY packageid ORDER BY ts DESC) AS latest_scanid,
    MIN(not_null_ts) OVER(PARTITION BY packageid) AS first_dispatch_time,
    MAX(not_null_ts) OVER(PARTITION BY packageid) AS last_dispatch_time,
    FIRST_VALUE(status) OVER(PARTITION BY packageid ORDER BY ts DESC) AS latest_status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY packageid ORDER BY not_null_ts DESC) AS line
  FROM YourTable 
)
WHERE line = 1
```

I found this type of trick working for me sometime ago, but I don't think I have ever see this documented explicitly, unless this might be obvious use - i never thought of it too much.